# Raising a matrix of math nodes in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm drawing a series of diagrams with many parallel edges, which I typeset with many instances of paths, `yshift`ed as necessary.

I'd like to use the same code for all diagrams, but some of them contain a number of displaystyle `\bigoplus` or `\prod`, which means my nodes are large and the text in the nodes is off-centre.

This results in the arrows not aligning properly. I would like to either shift all arrows by a set amount, or all nodes, which come from a `matrix of math nodes`.

I tried

```
postaction=decorate, decoration={raise=.5ex}
```

on the matrix of math nodes without success.

Is there another way of raising the whole matrix (or apply something to all paths)?

**Short example code**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,decorations}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-2.6pt,description/.style={fill=white,inner sep=2pt}]
        \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, column sep=1.5em, text height=2ex, text depth=.25ex, ]
                {
                \displaystyle \bigoplus_S Z & \displaystyle \bigoplus_{S \times S} Z & \displaystyle \bigoplus_{S \times S \times S} Z \cdots \\
                };
        \path[stealth-, line width=.5pt, font=\scriptsize]
                (m-1-2) edge (m-1-3)
                ;
        \path[transform canvas={yshift=.4ex}, stealth-, line width=.5pt, font=\scriptsize]
                (m-1-1) edge (m-1-2)
                ;
        \path[transform canvas={yshift=-.4ex}, stealth-, line width=.5pt, font=\scriptsize]
                (m-1-1) edge (m-1-2)
                ;
        \path[transform canvas={yshift=.8ex}, stealth-, line width=.5pt, font=\scriptsize]
                (m-1-2) edge (m-1-3)
                ;
        \path[transform canvas={yshift=-.8ex}, stealth-, line width=.5pt, font=\scriptsize]
                (m-1-2) edge (m-1-3)
                ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "aligning prperly" but adding nodes={minimum size=2cm} will make the spacing more even.